# How to merge a Series and DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

> If you came here looking for information on *how to
>   merge a `DataFrame` and `Series` on the index*, please look at [this
>   answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40762674/4909087).
>
> The OP's original intention was to ask *how to assign series elements
>   as columns to another DataFrame*. If you are interested in knowing the
>   answer to this, look at the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26266031/4909087) by EdChum.

---

Best I can come up with is

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1, 2], 'b':[3, 4]})  # see EDIT below
s = pd.Series({'s1':5, 's2':6})

for name in s.index:
    df[name] = s[name]

   a  b  s1  s2
0  1  3   5   6
1  2  4   5   6
```

Can anybody suggest better syntax / faster method?

My attempts:

```
df.merge(s)
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'columns'
```

and

```
df.join(s)
ValueError: Other Series must have a name
```

*EDIT* The first two answers posted highlighted a problem with my question, so please use the following to construct `df`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[np.nan, 2, 3], 'b':[4, 5, 6]}, index=[3, 5, 6])
```

with the final result

```
    a  b  s1  s2
3 NaN  4   5   6
5   2  5   5   6
6   3  6   5   6
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You could construct a dataframe from the series and then merge with the dataframe.
So you specify the data as the values but multiply them by the length, set the columns to the index and set params for `left_index` and `right_index` to True:

```
In [27]:

df.merge(pd.DataFrame(data = [s.values] * len(s), columns = s.index), left_index=True, right_index=True)
Out[27]:
   a  b  s1  s2
0  1  3   5   6
1  2  4   5   6
```

**EDIT** for the situation where you want the index of your constructed df from the series to use the index of the df then you can do the following:

```
df.merge(pd.DataFrame(data = [s.values] * len(df), columns = s.index, index=df.index), left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

This assumes that the indices match the length.

Answer (score 236):

**Update**
From v0.24.0 onwards, you can [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) on DataFrame and Series as long as the Series is named.

```
df.merge(s.rename('new'), left_index=True, right_index=True)
# If series is already named,
# df.merge(s, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

---

Nowadays, you can simply convert the Series to a DataFrame with [to_frame()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_frame.html). So (if joining on index):

```
df.merge(s.to_frame(), left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

Comment: Using the question's definitions of `df` and `s`, this answer returns for me an empty dataframe, *not* the result requested in the question.  We don't want to match on index; we want to broadcast the `s` values to all rows of `df`.

Comment: This is solving a different problem: "given a DataFrame and Series, how can they be merged on the index". OP's question was "assign each element of a Series as a new column in a DataFrame".

Answer (score 10):

Here's one way:

```
df.join(pd.DataFrame(s).T).fillna(method='ffill')
```

To break down what happens here...

`pd.DataFrame(s).T` creates a one-row DataFrame from `s` which looks like this:

```
   s1  s2
0   5   6
```

Next, `join` concatenates this new frame with `df`:

```
   a  b  s1  s2
0  1  3   5   6
1  2  4 NaN NaN
```

Lastly, the `NaN` values at index 1 are filled with the previous values in the column using `fillna` with the forward-fill (`ffill`) argument:

```
   a  b  s1  s2
0  1  3   5   6
1  2  4   5   6
```

---

To avoid using `fillna`, it's possible to use `pd.concat` to repeat the rows of the DataFrame constructed from `s`. In this case, the general solution is:

```
df.join(pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(s).T] * len(df), ignore_index=True))
```

---

Here's another solution to address the indexing challenge posed in the edited question:

```
df.join(pd.DataFrame(s.repeat(len(df)).values.reshape((len(df), -1), order='F'), 
        columns=s.index, 
        index=df.index))
```

`s` is transformed into a DataFrame by repeating the values and reshaping (specifying 'Fortran' order), and also passing in the appropriate column names and index. This new DataFrame is then joined to `df`.

Comment: Nice one-liner, a caveat is that any NaN's already in df will get filled as well.

Comment: @Nonth Thanks and good point. I've edited to include an alternative which avoid filling in `NaN` values.

Comment: What happened with EdChums original answer affects this revised answer. If I construct the df with, say, `index=[3, 5]`, the new columns contain nan's after your command.

Comment: @Nonth Edited again! It should now meet your new requirements.

Comment: your answer is 20x faster, but it's still a difference of ~100ms with df at 1e5 rows. My for loop is horrifically slow. BTW in your answer the `2` ought to be `len(df)` to be generally applicable.

Comment: Greetings! Your Edit 2 no longer appears to work. I get `ValueError: Shape of passed values is (2, 2), indices imply (2, 3)` when I try and run this.

Comment: @coldspeed: thanks for pointing out the issue! I've edited the answer: hopefully the code works and is more general now.

Answer (score 3):

Nowadays, much simpler and concise solution can achieve the same task. Leveraging the  capability of [`DataFrame.apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) to turn a Series into columns of its belonging DataFrame, we can use:

```
df.join(df.apply(lambda x: s, axis=1))
```

Result:

```
     a  b  s1  s2
3  NaN  4   5   6
5  2.0  5   5   6
6  3.0  6   5   6
```

Here, we used [`DataFrame.apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with a simple lambda function as the applied function on `axis=1`.  The applied lambda function simply just returns the Series s:

```
df.apply(lambda x: s, axis=1)
```

Result:

```
   s1  s2
3   5   6
5   5   6
6   5   6
```

The result has already inherited the row index of the original DataFrame `df`.  Consequently, we can simply join `df` with this interim result by [`DataFrame.join()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to get the desired final result (since they have the same row index).

This capability of [`DataFrame.apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) to turn a Series into columns of its belonging DataFrame is well documented in the [official document](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) as follows:

> By default (result_type=None), the final return type is inferred from
> the return type of the applied function.

---

> The default behaviour (result_type=None) depends on the return value of the
> applied function: list-like results will be returned as a Series of
> those. However ***if the apply function returns a Series these are
> expanded to columns***.

The [official document](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) also includes example of such usage:

> Returning a Series inside the function is similar to passing
> result_type='expand'. The resulting column names will be the Series
> index.

```
df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series([1, 2], index=['foo', 'bar']), axis=1)   

   foo  bar
0    1    2
1    1    2
2    1    2
```

Comment: @jezrael  Totally agree that `apply` is mostly a convenient tool than performance efficient tool, especially on `axis=1`, though there are [some legitimate uses of `apply`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54433552/15070697) in some use cases.

Comment: sure, I dont think apply is bad, only be carefull for use it ;)

Answer (score 1):

If I could suggest setting up your dataframes like this (auto-indexing):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[np.nan, 1, 2], 'b':[4, 5, 6]})
```

then you can set up your s1 and s2 values thus (using shape() to return the number of rows from df):

```
s = pd.DataFrame({'s1':[5]*df.shape[0], 's2':[6]*df.shape[0]})
```

then the result you want is easy:

```
display (df.merge(s, left_index=True, right_index=True))
```

Alternatively, just add the new values to your dataframe df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[nan, 1, 2], 'b':[4, 5, 6]})
df['s1']=5
df['s2']=6
display(df)
```

Both return:

```
     a  b  s1  s2
0  NaN  4   5   6
1  1.0  5   5   6
2  2.0  6   5   6
```

If you have another list of data (instead of just a single value to apply), and you know it is in the same sequence as df, eg:

```
s1=['a','b','c']
```

then you can attach this in the same way:

```
df['s1']=s1
```

returns:

```
     a  b s1
0  NaN  4  a
1  1.0  5  b
2  2.0  6  c
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily set a pandas.DataFrame column to a constant. This constant can be an int such as in your example. If the column you specify isn't in the df, then pandas will create a new column with the name you specify. So after your dataframe is constructed, (from your question):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[np.nan, 2, 3], 'b':[4, 5, 6]}, index=[3, 5, 6])
```

You can just run:

```
df['s1'], df['s2'] = 5, 6
```

You could write a loop or comprehension to make it do this for all the elements in a list of tuples, or keys and values in a dictionary depending on how you have your real data stored.

Answer (score 0):

If `df` is a `pandas.DataFrame` then `df['new_col']= Series list_object of length len(df)` will add the or Series list_object as a column named `'new_col'`. `df['new_col']= scalar` (such as 5 or 6 in your case) also works and is equivalent to `df['new_col']= [scalar]*len(df)`

So a two-line code serves the purpose:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1, 2], 'b':[3, 4]})
s = pd.Series({'s1':5, 's2':6})
for x in s.index:    
    df[x] = s[x]

Output: 
   a  b  s1  s2
0  1  3   5   6
1  2  4   5   6
```