# How to merge multidimensional dataframe and series of different length?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, series

Is there a way to merge a multidimensional dataframe with a series of different lengths?
There are so many ways to combine df's. I've read about joining, concatenating, appending and merging. I don't know which one to use. Also, all have many optional parameters, what makes it even more difficult to understand. Can someone clarify the documentation (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html), specifically on how to merge a dataframe and series of different lengths?

For example, I would like to merge the following multi-dimensional dataframe,

```
d = {'Name': ['Kitty', 'Harry', 'Bear', 'Sam', 'Max', 'Hunter', 'Fluffy'], 'Favloc': ['couch', 'windowsill', 'bed', 'basket', 'floor', 'carpet', 'haybale'], 'Pet': ['Cat', 'Cat', 'Cat', 'Dog', 'Dog', 'Dog', 'Hamster']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df = df.set_index(['Pet', 'Name'])

print (df)
                 Favloc
Pet     Name           
Cat     Kitty     couch
        Harry   windows
        Bear        bed
        Sam      basket
Dog     Max       floor
        Hunter   carper
```

with the following Series, s1:

```
s1 = pd.Series([3,3,1], index=['Cat','Dog','Hamster'])
```

I would like the result to be:

```
                      Favloc
Pet     cnts Name           
Cat     3    Kitty     couch
             Harry   windows
             Bear        bed
             Sam      basket
Dog     3    Max       floor
             Hunter   carper
Hamster 1    Fluffy  Haybale
```

I already tried

```
result = df.join(s1)
```

But that throws an error:

```
Cannot join with no level specified and no overlapping names
```

I understand that I didn't specify a level, but I don't know how to specify it. Should I say level 1, because I'd like cnts to be on the 1 level index? (with Favloc being level 0?
Also, I don't understand 'with no overlapping names', because cat, dog and hamster overlap, right?

I also tried

```
result = pd.concat([df, s1])
```

This resulted in a dataframe with NAN in every column where I would like to see the cnts.

Then I tried:

```
result = pd.merge(df, s1)
```

And I got:
can not merge DataFrame with instance of type

I tried al of them with all sorts of arguments but I don't think it helps to show everything I tried? I think I tried to much, because I don't really understand how merging a multidimensional dataframe and series of different length works.

I've seen related questions, but all with dataframes with just one level, like: [How to merge a Series and DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26265819/how-to-merge-a-series-and-dataframe/40762674#40762674)
So, how to merge a multidimensional dataframe and series of different lengths?

Comment: Have you tried a `reset_index` on both data frames and then joined them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) with `rename` and parameter `on`, then [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`DataFrame.reorder_levels`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reorder_levels.html):

```
result = (df.join(s1.rename('cnts'), on='Pet')
           .set_index('cnts', append=True)
           .reorder_levels([0,2,1]))
print (result)
                      Favloc
Pet     cnts Name           
Cat     3    Kitty     couch
             Harry   windows
             Bear        bed
             Sam      basket
Dog     3    Max       floor
             Hunter   carper
Hamster 1    Fluffy  Haybale
```

Or use [`Index.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.map.html):

```
idx = df.index.get_level_values('Pet').map(s1.rename('cnts').get)
result = df.set_index(idx, append=True).reorder_levels([0,2,1])
print (result)
                      Favloc
Pet     cnts Name           
Cat     3    Kitty     couch
             Harry   windows
             Bear        bed
             Sam      basket
Dog     3    Max       floor
             Hunter   carper
Hamster 1    Fluffy  Haybale
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried both. The first, DataFrame.join, throws an error: KeyError: 'Pet'. Index.map throws another error: 'Series' object is not callable

Comment: @Hibisceae - Change `idx = df.index.get_level_values('Pet').map(s1).rename('cnts')` to `idx = df.index.get_level_values('Pet').map(s1.get).rename('cnts')`

Comment: @Hibisceae - It is problem some oldier pandas version, if use last `0.24+` it working nice with no `.get` too.

Comment: That's it! It threw: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'rename', Workaround: `s1 = s1.rename('cnts')` and then idx = df.index.get_level_values('Pet').map(s1.get) result = df.set_index(idx, append=True).reorder_levels([0,2,1]) Problem solved. Thanks!

Comment: @Hibisceae - yes, it is same like `idx = df.index.get_level_values('Pet').map(s1.rename('cnts').get)`. Thanks, glad to help. Don't forget to accept the answer, if it suits you! :)