# How to convert a Pandas series into a Dataframe for merging

Tags: python, pandas, series

I am fairly new to Python, I am trying to convert the Series coming out from groupby() into a dataframe, that I will merge to the main df. However, to_frame() seems not working as it keeps returning a series not a dataframe.Any help will be greatly appreciated See following code:

```
IN: pf_avg = df.groupby('release_year').profit.mean() 
    pf_avg.to_frame()
    type(pf_avg)

OUT: pandas.core.series.Series

IN: df_pf_avg = df.merge(pf_avg, left_on= 'release_year', right_index= True)
    df_pf_avg.head()

OUT: ValueError: can not merge DataFrame with instance of type <class 
    'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

Comment: First of all, `to_frame()` *returns a new object which is a data frame*. It does not *change* the object that called the method. So you should do `pf_avg = pf_avg.to_frame()` to see the difference. In addition, you likely want just `df['new_column'] = df.groupby('release_year').profit.transform('mean')`

Comment: From v0.24, you _don't_ need to convert from series to dataframe. Pass it to df.merge directly. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40762674/4909087)

Comment: thank you very much, I don't know how to reward you guys if this is a possibility.