# Converting Dataframe with multplie values in one cell

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe looking as follows

```
id                          value       index
5eb3cbcc434474213e58b49a    [1,2,3,4,6] [0,1,2,3,4]
5eb3f335434474213e58b49d    [1,2,3,4]   [0,2,3,4]
5eb3f853434474213e58b49f    [1,2,3,4]   [0,2,3,4]
5eb40395434474213e58b4a2    [1,2,3,4]   [0,1,2,3]
5eb40425434474213e58b4a5    [1,2]       [0,2]
```

I try to convert this dataframe in the folllowing matter, as that the index aims as a title over each individual value, looking something like this:

```
id                          0   1   2   3   4
5eb3cbcc434474213e58b49a    1   2   3   4   6
5eb3f335434474213e58b49d    1   Nan 2   3   4
5eb3f853434474213e58b49f    1   Nan 2   3   4
5eb40395434474213e58b4a2    1   2   3   4   Nan
5eb40425434474213e58b4a5    1   Nan 2   Nan Nan
```

I tried to firstly split the List of Lists:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame(df.Value.str.split(',').tolist(), index=df.Index).stack()
new_df = new_df.reset_index([0, 'Index'])
new_df.columns = ['Value', 'Index']
```

However I recieve the Error

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

What causes this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create list of dictionaries in list comrehension and pass to `DataFrame` constructor, last append to original if dont need slow solution:

```
L = [dict(zip(x, y)) for x, y in zip(df.pop('index'), df.pop('value'))]

df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(L, index=df.index))
print (df)
                         id  0    1  2    3    4
0  5eb3cbcc434474213e58b49a  1  2.0  3  4.0  6.0
1  5eb3f335434474213e58b49d  1  NaN  2  3.0  4.0
2  5eb3f853434474213e58b49f  1  NaN  2  3.0  4.0
3  5eb40395434474213e58b4a2  1  2.0  3  4.0  NaN
4  5eb40425434474213e58b4a5  1  NaN  2  NaN  NaN
```

**Performance**:

```
#5k rows
df = pd.concat([df] * 1000, ignore_index=True)


In [123]: %timeit df.set_index('id').apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x['value'], index=x['index']), axis=1).reset_index()
2.14 s ± 7.48 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

#similar code, because pop failed for test performance
In [124]: %timeit df.drop(['index','value'], axis=1).join(pd.DataFrame([dict(zip(x, y)) for x, y in zip(df['index'], df['value'])], index=df.index))
15.2 ms ± 87.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)


#50k rows
df = pd.concat([df] * 10000, ignore_index=True)

In [126]: %timeit df.set_index('id').apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x['value'], index=x['index']), axis=1).reset_index()
24.2 s ± 1.14 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [127]: %timeit df.drop(['index','value'], axis=1).join(pd.DataFrame([dict(zip(x, y)) for x, y in zip(df['index'], df['value'])], index=df.index))
128 ms ± 821 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`.apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) together with [`pd.Series()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.html), as follows:

```
df = df.set_index('id').apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x['value'], index=x['index']), axis=1).reset_index()


print(df)

                         id    0    1    2    3    4
0  5eb3cbcc434474213e58b49a  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  6.0
1  5eb3f335434474213e58b49d  1.0  NaN  2.0  3.0  4.0
2  5eb3f853434474213e58b49f  1.0  NaN  2.0  3.0  4.0
3  5eb40395434474213e58b4a2  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  NaN
4  5eb40425434474213e58b4a5  1.0  NaN  2.0  NaN  NaN
```

This makes use of the [`.apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) function feature that:

> The default behaviour (None) depends on the return value of the
> applied function: list-like results will be returned as a Series of
> those. However ***if the apply function returns a Series these are
> expanded to columns***.

This feature is handy in helping us give a simple solution to problems requiring expanding data onto columns while at the same time incorporating new columns into existing data by retaining and prorogating existing row indexes to these new columns.  I used it to provide a [simple answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66968927/15070697) to a classic question: [How to merge a Series and DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26265819/15070697).

Comment: hmmm, thinking about performance, I think it is bad.

Comment: @jezrael  You are right, this is good for small dataset.

Comment: Btw, I am really surprise such difference, interesting